# Problem with biber: file.bcf is malformed

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Yo, I'm having problems in trying to load a proper bibliography containing the url. I'm trying to use biber together with an output produced by BibDesk. However I can't even run biber properly.

I'm also using TexShop (the one in MacTeX) and I have already configured my editor by changing the BibTeX Engine to biber in TeXShop>Preferences>Engine

One example of output generated by BibDesk is HoTT.bib

```
   @article{Kapulkin:2012rm,
   Abstract = {In this largely expository paper, we construct and investigate a model of the Univalent Foundations of Mathematics in the category of simplicial sets.},
   Author = {Chris Kapulkin and Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine},
   Date-Added = {2017-02-05 09:31:04 +0000},
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-05 09:31:04 +0000},
   Eprint = {1211.2851},
   Month = {11},
   Title = {The Simplicial Model of Univalent Foundations (after Voevodsky)},
   Url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851},
   Year = {2012},
   Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851}}
```

, which looks like syntactically correct.

I'm trying to compile the file HoTT.tex. Simply for sake of completeness, I will list all the packages I need to use , document class and new commands in my .tex file. I believe they're 
not the problem though

```
   \documentclass[12pt, a4 paper, twoside]{article}
   \usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amscd, amsthm}
   \usepackage{mathrsfs}
   \usepackage{indentfirst}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}%preciso ver depois !!!%
   \usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
   \usepackage{enumitem}
   \usepackage{authblk}
   \usepackage[sort cites=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

  \providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1}


  \keywords{Homotopy Type Theory, Categorical Logic, Homotopy Theory, Quasi-categories, \ensuremath{(\infty,1)}-categories, Higher Elementary Topoi} 

  \begin{document}
  \nocite{*}

  \bibliography{HoTT} 

  \end{document}
```

When trying to run biber I get the following error

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'HoTT.blg'
ERROR - HoTT.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted    HoTT.bbl
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Comment: A malformed bcf indicates a faulty pdflatex run. So check for errors there. One obvious error is the misplacement of \bibliography: Use `\addbibresource{HoTT.bib}` in the *preamble*.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your comment! Working now! You saved me! You can post this as an answer. By the way I have read somewhere that \addbibresource and \bibliography can be used interchangeably.

Comment: You are right, `\bibliography` still works as a (deprecated) alternative ... but (as Ulrike pointed out) *still* only in the **preamble**. And better not to use it, because it is officially deprecated.

Comment: @PaulStanley Could you expand on why its deprecated? It's just curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A malformed `bcf` indicates a faulty pdflatex run. So check for errors there.

One obvious error is the misplacement of `\bibliography`: Use `\addbibresource{HoTT.bib}` (or the deprecated `\bibliography`) with biblatex always in the preamble.